# searching cstring for operators

Tags: c++, character, cstring

For an assignment we are given an equation in reverse polish notation. For this example I will use: `2 3 8 * + $`  The `$` is for denoting the end of the expression. Using a stack, we output the answer.

I have been using:

```
getline(cin, input, '&');
input.c_str();
```

to read in the equation and then turn it into a c_string so I can look at the individual elements in the input.

After, I need to check for a few things.  If the element is a digit I need to push it onto the stack.  If it is white space I need to skip over it.

```
if (isdigit(input[i]))
{
    push();
    i++;
}
else if (isspace(input[i]))
{
    i++;
}
```

Now is what has me stuck.  If I hit an operator (in this case `*`) I need to pop the top two elements off the stack and 'operate them' and push the result back to the stack.  However, I don't know of anything that would allow me to recognize that they are operators. It is probably a silly question, but help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just off-hand, is your input guaranteed to be seperated by whitespace?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yessir, it will always have a space between each value.

Comment: What if you input contains multi digits numbers: `12 321 + $` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I still need to think about how to account for that as well.

Comment: @ViscousRandom just do not put digit at once on stack - but keep counting the number - unless you get any non digit character - then put the number on stack, BTW for reverse polish notation you need only  stack of numbers - nothing more - see my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are only about 4 or 5 operators. check them with something like:

```
if (input[i] == '*') {...}
```

Comment: pfft. i'd use a switch and strtok(), but odds are runtime-libraries are rather limited for their assignment. Then again, i see isdigit(), isspace(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a functions [map](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/), and match the operators

```
std::map<char, void (*)(char *)> operators;

operators['*'] = &mult;
operators['+'] = &add;
...
```

and in your conditionnal statement

```
if (isdigit(input[i]))
    {
       push();
       i++;
    }
else if (isspace(input[i]))
    {
       i++;
    }
else if (operators.find(input[i]) != operators.end())
    {
       operators[input[i]](input);
    }
```

This way, you will be able to easily add new operators to your calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no "built-in" way. I would just write an IsOperator(char ch) function. And then do something like:

```
int IsOperator(char ch)
{
    // either add more operators or use a table, etc. here
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*')
      return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

If you have multi-char operators, like '==', it gets a little more complicated because you have to peek ahead, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing reverse polish notation calculator then on stack you have only numbers, or digits like in your example. BTW don't you accept multi-digits numbers?

Consider two cases, in both you need only `std::stack<int> numbers;`:

- You have digit character `c` - just put number on stack:

code:

```
numbers,push(c - '0');
```

- You have  operator, let say '+', you replaces top two numbers by their sum:

code:

```
 if (numbers.size() < 2) {
     throw std::runtime_error("Too little numbers for +");
 }
 int a = numbers.top(); 
 numbers.pop();
 numbers.top() += a;
```

- You have  '$', check if there is only one number on stack, it is the result:

code:

```
  if (numbers.size() != 1) {
     throw std::runtime_error("There should be only one!");
   }
   int result = numbers.top();
   numbers.pop();
```